# the same language as each other / the same language with each other

Tags: as

> Most people in these countries speak **the same language as each other** – English. [There was a comparison between two countries in the text.]
>
> Most people in these countries speak **the same language with each other** – English.

I can't understand the connection between "the same language as" & "each other" in that sentence. Isn't "the same language with each other" more natural?

Comment: In English we always say **the same,,, as** and never **the same... with**. However, in this sentence the words _as each other_ could perfectly well be left out.

Comment: I would suggest that, in the UK at least, one would more likely say **Most people in these countries share a common language - English** This would be understood as speaking and writing it.

Comment: _Share a common language_ may be a little more formal. Most people seem to [**speak**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=speak+the+same+language%2Cshare+a+common+language&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspeak%20the%20same%20language%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshare%20a%20common%20language%3B%2Cc0) the same language.

Comment: yeah "share a common language" is very formal